# Android Kotlin - Create dialog inside a callback function

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to create a dialog inside a callback `onSuccess()` which again is inside the `onCreate()` method of the activity, but the dialog view doesn't show up.

When I call `createDialog()` directly inside the `onCreate()` it works. What could be the reason why it's not working in the `onSuccess()` callback function? `onSuccess()` and `createDialog()` definitely get called because the `println` show up.

Code:

```
class BleDevicesControlActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var device: BluetoothDevice? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ble_devices_control)

        connectToDevice(object : BleCommunication.OnConnectionListener {
            override fun onSuccess() {
                    println("onSuccess called")
                    createDialog()
            }
            override fun onFailure() {
                    println("onFailure called")
            }
        })
    }

    private fun connectToDevice(onConnectionListener : BleCommunication.OnConnectionListener) {
        bleCommunication.connect(device!!, onConnectionListener)
    }

    private fun createDialog() {
        println("createDialog called")
        val dialogInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this)
        val alertDialogView = dialogInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_alert, null)
        val alertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this).create()
        alertDialog.setView(alertDialogView)
        alertDialog.show()
    }

}
```

Comment: make sure they are thread safe and the `onSuccess` callback is on the mainThread to create a dialog, if not wrap it around `runOnUi{ createDialog() }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 override fun onSuccess() {
      println("onSuccess called")
      runOnUiThread { createDialog() }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set view to dialog builder:

```
private fun createDialog() {
    println("createDialog called")
    val dialogInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this)
    val alertDialogView = dialogInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_alert, null)
    val alertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this).setView(alertDialogView).create()
    alertDialog.show()
}
```